# Как создать директорию по ранее полученным данным

Tags: python-3.x, ос

К примеру есть неизвестный сервер, и я беру id сервера. С другого сервера тоже беру его id через команду сбора. И теперь надо создать папку с нашим id.

Я пытался так:

```
pach1 = f'"D:\Desktop\test\{команда взятия id сервера}"'
os.makedirs(pach1)
```

Но ничего не получилось

Comment: Попробуйте убрать двойные кавычки. В таком виде они являются частью строки. И, пожалуйста, поясните, что значит "ничего не получилось". Может, ошибка связана с чем-то другим.

Comment: Ошибка свызана именно с этим, тк без этого кода всё работает. И с моим модулем, будет сложно указать конкретную ошибку, тк он просто не выполняет условие с ошибкой, не выдовая исключений(короче всё там сложно по конкретике)

Comment: Хм, ошибка была и правда связана с ковычками, @nomnoms12 спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите двойные кавычки, они являются частью строки.

***Пример:***

```py
pach1 = f'D:\Desktop\test\{команда взятия id сервера}'
```